# Setting up a connection to Online MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

all of the examples, unfortunately on the net are consumed of downloading a MySQL database to your computer rather than taking advantage of Online Database.

What should I replace the following code to get data from an online db rather than a 3306 typical desktop MySQL;

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DBNAME", "usrname", "pswd") ;
```

Comment: What is "an online DB"? What about just replacing "localhost" by the remote host? Show a minimal understanding of the problem -- youre just asking the question!

Comment: sorry I meant database by db

Comment: Thanks, but thats not what causes the misunderstanding. Is "an online DB" an exposed MySQL server? Which protocol, which authentication etc -- all that is information one would need to answer the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since not too much information was given, we will use an example - let's say the database is located at `user3129325.com`, and is hosted by a web hosting provider that allows remote SQL.  If you wanted to connect to the database named "DBNAME" (using the same name as in your example), you would want to use the following command:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://user3129325.com:3306/DBNAME", "usrname", "pswd") ;
```

Just simply replace `localhost` with the URL of the remote MySQL database.

Comment: Usually the easiest things are the hardest to figure out. Much appreciated along with the down votes :) It was worth the down votes, will accept your answer in 6 minutes!